# Output multiple registry values per key

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, registry

I want to output both DisplayName and DisplayVersion of each program installed.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %a in (
  'reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s ^
  | findstr /c:"DisplayName" /c:"DisplayVersion"'
) do @echo %b
```

It does output both of them one per line but I want to display them on one line, how would you do that?

```
> DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should check both 32bit and 64bit registries. If I don't specify which one, then my REG QUERY searches only 64bit by default.

Not all program keys have DisplayName and/or DisplayVersion.

The code below lists the full key if DisplayName is not present, and lists an empty version if DisplayVersion is not present. Both 32bit and 64bit registries are searched.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "key="
set "name="
set "ver="
for %%s in (32 64) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /reg:%%s 2^>nul') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    if "!ln:~0,4!" equ "HKEY" (
      if defined name (echo "!name!","!ver!") else if defined key echo "!key!","!ver!"
      set "name="
      set "ver="
      set "key=%%A"
    ) else for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ("!ln!") do (
      if "%%A" equ "DisplayName" set "name=%%C"
      if "%%A" equ "DisplayVersion" set "ver=%%C"
    )
  )
)
if defined name (echo "!name!","!ver!") else if defined key echo "!key!","!ver!"
```

Answer (score 0):

*The easiest method would be to just output the information directly within Windows PowerShell but that would be directly contrary to the tags you've applied to this question.*

Here therefore is a batch file which uses Powershell:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "KP=Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

PowerShell -C "GP HKLM:\%KP%\*|Select DisplayName,DisplayVersion|FT -A -H"
Pause
```

*You may remove `\Wow6432Node` from `line 2` if you're not using this on a 64bit Operating System.*

---

It is possible for the `DisplayName` output to be truncated due to their character lengths and cmd.exe's buffersize. This can be worked around using the following, *(possibly crude)*, code:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "KP=Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
Set/A W=90,H=120

PowerShell -C "&{$H=Get-Host;$R=$H.UI.RawUI;$B=$R.BufferSize;"^
 "$W=$R.WindowSize;$B.Width=If (%W% -GT $W.Width) {%W%} Else {$W.Width};"^
 "$B.Height=If (%H% -GT $W.Height) {%H%} Else {$W.height};$R.BufferSize=$B};"^
 "GP HKLM:\%KP%\*|Select DisplayName,DisplayVersion|FT -A -H"
Pause
```

In the above code you can adjust that height/width on `line 3` as required, *this may be necessary if you have some very long `DisplayName`'s or a huge list of installed software under that key*.